# Comparing WindowsIdentity.Current.Name on Server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-identity

I am currently reviewing a system with a wcf service and a client application that connects to it via tcp, using Windows Auth.

On certain actions it is required to store the user name on an objects property, send it to the service and compare it to the credentials that are passed from the client. The object is than further processed.

It has recently been discovered by the client, that this is not always working as expected. I have looked into the issue and discovered that there are some cases where on the client and server side different user names are used (it differs in the usage of lower and upper case).

I have installed a workaround (obviously using a IgnoreCase option in the string.Equals) however i am interested in the real fix.

On the client it uses WindowsIdentity.Current.Name as the string and on the service side it uses ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name as the string.

What is the correct way of doing this comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Are the client and server on the same domain? If so, store and compare the `User` property on your `WindowsIdentity` objects instead of the username. This is the user's Security Identifier (SID), which is (simplifying) a unique numeric user ID in the Windows world.

You can store a string representation of a `SecurityIdentifier` object using its `Value` property:

```
string storedSid = WindowsIdentity.Current.User.Value;
```

You can then reconstruct a SecurityIdentifier using this, and compare it on the service side:

```
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(storedSid);
// SecurityIdentifer defines operator ==
bool equalUsers = sid == ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.User;
```